# Upgrade to camel set of jars 3.x failing with ClassNotFoundException for ActiveMQDestination

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm upgrading to Camel 3.x from Camel 2.x in my application which is using camel, activemq and spring. While starting the application, startup is blocked with the below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination
        at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.camel.component.activemq.converter.ActiveMQConverterLoader.registerConverters(ActiveMQConverterLoader.java:28) ~[camel-activemq-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.activemq.converter.ActiveMQConverterLoader.load(ActiveMQConverterLoader.java:24) ~[camel-activemq-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.loadCoreAndFastTypeConverters(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:167) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter.doInit(DefaultTypeConverter.java:66) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83) ~[camel-api-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.initService(ServiceHelper.java:55) ~[camel-api-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.internalAddService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1488) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doAddService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1424) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doAddService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1419) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doAddService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1415) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.setTypeConverter(AbstractCamelContext.java:1797) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getOrCreateTypeConverter(AbstractCamelContext.java:1789) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doBuild(AbstractCamelContext.java:2514) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.build(BaseService.java:63) ~[camel-api-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.<init>(AbstractCamelContext.java:344) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SimpleCamelContext.<init>(SimpleCamelContext.java:109) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.<init>(DefaultCamelContext.java:112) ~[camel-core-engine-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.<init>(DefaultCamelContext.java:86) ~[camel-core-engine-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
```

There are camel jars with version 3.4.0, activemq-client and activemq-core and spring 5.0.6 jars in classpath. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you please add your pom file?

Comment: Yes, please share your pom and also specify your packaging. This often happens with packaged jar with dependencies (fat jar), which needs special handling of type converters to function correctly.

Comment: You should use camel-activemq as dependency and NOT activemq-camel. Its documented in the migration guide.

Comment: Thanks. There was an issue with the classpath. Pointing to the right set of all the activemq jars in the application in the classpath solved this problem.